# Custom TextInputLayout not applying if password toggle enabled

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design

I have the following setup for a TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText:

values/themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Base.AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        ...
        <item name="textInputStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.TextInputLayout</item>
        ...
    </style>
</resources>
```

I then have multiple folders for multiple screen densities but I'm having issues within the hdpi folder. Here are the definitions for my TextInputLayout styles within the xxxhdpi folder and the hdpi folder:

values-hdpi/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    ...
    <style name="Widget.MyApp.TextInputLayout" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent</item>
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.TextInputLayout</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.App.TextInputLayout" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="textAppearanceSubtitle1">@style/TextAppearance.MyApp.EditText</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceCaption">@style/TextAppearance.MyApp.EditTextHint</item>
        <item name="editTextStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.TextInputEditText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.MyApp.TextInputEditText" parent="Base.Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText">
        <item name="android:paddingStart">@dimen/spacing_medium</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/spacing_semi_medium</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/spacing_semi_medium</item>
    </style>
    ...
</resources>
```

values-xxxhdpi/styles.xml

```
    <style name="Widget.MyApp.TextInputLayout" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent</item>
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.TextInputLayout</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.App.TextInputLayout" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="textAppearanceSubtitle1">@style/TextAppearance.MyApp.EditText</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceCaption">@style/TextAppearance.MyApp.EditTextHint</item>
    </style>
```

As you can see, I don't override anything in the xxxhdpi version (nothing to do with the editTextStyle anyway) but I do in the hdpi. The issue I am facing is that although what I have works for most TextInputLayout elements I have, as soon as I have a password one with an endIconMode, the padding I set seems to be overridden by some parameter associated with said endIcon. Here is an example of what happens:

[image: Difference in TextInputLayout sizes]

Although the difference is subtle, it is noticeable and makes the whole thing pretty uncomfortable to look at (exaggeration but you see what I mean from a user standpoint).

I would like to know if there is anything I could do (as in override different properties or create a custom TextInputLayout although I'd prefer not to) to have the padding apply to the endIcon as well

Comment: I take it that the problem is that the password field is taller than the email field. I think that you are hitting up against a minimum height set for the end icon. See [this](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/res/layout/design_text_input_end_icon.xml) which is the layout for the end icon.

Comment: Yep, that would be the thing I was looking for. I hadn't thought about minimum values in regards to accessibility ! Thank you so much for this !

Comment: You can use the Layout Inspector in Android Studio to look at the values for any displayed view such as padding, min height, etc.